# libc++ vs VC++: Can non-UTF conversions be done with wstring_convert?

Tags: c++, c++11, non-unicode

The C++11's `std::wstring_convert` works great<sup>`*`</sup> for the standard UTF-8 <-> UTF-16/UCS2/UCS4 conversions. However, when I attempted to instantiate a wstring_convert or wbuffer_convert with a facet not from `<codecvt>`, it didn't work as expected:

```
// works as expected
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> ucs4conv;

// Now, by analogy, I want to try this:
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> gbconv(
        new std::codecvt_byname<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>("zh_CN.gb18030"));
```

Clang++ errors out saying "calling a protected destructor of codecvt<> in ~wstring_convert"

Visual Studio allows it (although it lacks that locale, but that's another story), because its wstring_convert pawns the lifetime management of the facet pointer off to a locale object it holds as a member, and locales know how to delete pointers to all facets.

Is Visual Studio right and libc++ wrong?

<sub>`*` as implemented in clang++-2.9/libc++-svn and Visual Studio 2010 EE SP1, the following example works on both, but not in GCC, sadly: https://ideone.com/hywz6</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am admittedly biased in this answer.  But I will attempt to back up my claims with references to N3290 (which is unfortunately no longer publicly available).  And I will also offer a solution.

**Analysis:**

The synopsis of `wstring_convert` in [conversions.string]/p2 includes:

```
private:
  byte_string byte_err_string;  // exposition only
  wide_string wide_err_string;  // exposition only
  Codecvt *cvtptr;              // exposition only
  state_type cvtstate;          // exposition only
  size_t cvtcount;              // exposition only
```

The "exposition only" means that the `wstring_convert` doesn't have to have these members in this order by this spelling.  But "exposition only" members are used to describe the effects of various members, and those specifications *are* binding.

And so the question appears to become:

> What is the specification of `~wstring_convert()`?

This is found in p17 of the same section ([conversions.string]):

> `~wstring_convert();`
>
> *Effects:* The destructor shall delete `cvtptr`.

That implies to me that `~Codecvt()` must be accessible, and therefore libc++ is following the C++11 specification.

I would also agree that this is a royal pain in the butt.

**Solution:**

Having all of the C++98/03 facets have protected destructors has turned out to be very inconvenient.  Here's an adaptor that can take any facet and give it a public destructor:

```
template <class Facet>
class usable_facet
    : public Facet
{
public:
    template <class ...Args>
        usable_facet(Args&& ...args)
            : Facet(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
    ~usable_facet() {}
};
```

You can now use this general purpose adaptor in your code:

```
typedef usable_facet<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> C;
std::wstring_convert<C> gbconv(new C("zh_CN.gb18030"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It also says that the template argument Codecvt `meets the requirements of the standard code-conversion facet std::codecvt<` (§ 22.3.3.2.2/3). And the std::codecvt is defined with a protected dtor.  Perhaps "shall delete `cvtptr`" does not mean "same as `delete cvtptr;`"? Thanks for the wrapper though.

Comment: I'll open an inquiry.  At this point I'm unsure of what the best resolution would be.  It seems a shame to me to go to the expense of creating a new `locale` to hold `Codecvt*` where otherwise a simple pointer store would do.

Comment: Oh, just looked it up.  The issue has already been opened and decided NAD:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#721

Comment: @Howard : Marking the issue as NAD because "*codecvt isn't intended for beginning programmers*" seems like a bit of a cop out. Is there any possibility of reopening the issue?

Comment: Anyone can open an issue.  If you go this route you should point directly to the issue you want reopened, else your complaint will be immediately marked as a duplicate.  Here are the instructions for opening an issue:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#submit_issue

Comment: @ildjarn - From what I remember, the reason for the NAD was that the designers of wstring_convert were well aware of the problem all along. Thus technically not a defect, but works-as-designed.

Comment: @Bo : Except that in this case, 'works-as-designed' apparently means 'doesn't work without extra, pointless effort'. :-/ (Also, I did note that you submitted the original issue, so I figured you had more insight to offer. :-])